# Как правильно сделать прокрутку числа?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Есть блок, в котором есть число.

Мне нужно, чтобы при некоторых действиях (в моем случае - это ajax запрос на получение скидки, не столь важно), выполнялась анимированная прокрутка чисел.

Написал простенький скрипт на jQuery, но что-то сделал не так: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/yPOJRQ)

```js
$('#count').animate({
  numberValue: 500
}, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function() {
    $('#count').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
  }
});
```

```css
#count {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="count">1699</span>
```

Как сделать, чтобы число прокручивалось из начального в конечное, т.е. из того, что сейчас в блоке, к заданному в объекте, а не с нуля до заданного? Заранее спасибо!

Да, хочется также добавить, что желательно, чтобы число могло идти с бОльшего к меньшему и наоборот, т.е. не только от меньшего к бОльшему.

Comment: будь умничкой, сделай сниппет вместо ссылки на codepen

Comment: в следующий раз будешь сниппет делать?)

Comment: @user268670 буду-буду))))

Comment: кстати, у тебя много вопросов, в которых дали ответ в комментариях, ты же можешь перенести комментарии в самоответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
$('#count').animate({numberValue: 500}, { ...
```

на

```
$({numberValue: 1699}).animate({numberValue: 500}, { ...
```

Сниппет:

```js
$({numberValue: 77} /* начальное значение */).animate(
  {numberValue: 20}, /* конечное значение (не включительно) */
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() { 
      $('#count').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    } 
  }
);
```

```css
#count {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="count">число тут ни на что не влияет</span>
```